# JavaScript runtime error: 'goinstant' is undefined

Tags: javascript, goinstant

I'm new at goinstant.  I'm following the example and get the following error at runtime.

JavaScript runtime error: 'goinstant' is undefined

here is the code:

```
<script src="https://cdn.goinstant.net/v1/platform.min.js"></script>
<script>
var url = "https://goinstant.net/xxxxxxx/test";
var connect = goinstant.connect(url);
connect.then(function (result) {
    var conn = result.connection;
    var lobby = result.rooms[0];
    alert(lobby);
});
</script>
```

Am I missing Something?  I should caveat this by saying I got an error before this one regarding the platform.min.js .  The error is:

JavaScript critical error at line 1, column 1 in https://cdn.goinstant.net/v1/platform.min.js\n\nSCRIPT1014: Invalid character

Comment: Which means the script wasn't loaded successfully. Also make sure you are actually using two separate script elements to load the library and for your code.

Comment: Thank you Felix, I originally had placed two script tags but I was still getting the same error.  Thank you for your fast responses.

Comment: Is `<script src="https://cdn.goinstant.net/v1/platform.min.js"><script>` a typo? or you mistyped the closing </script> tag.

Comment: It was bad formatting on my part.  I've revised the code as is now. Thank you. But still getting the error.  I'm using Visual Studio 2013, MVC4 Mobile Application.

Comment: you can use [this](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html#L24-L25) snippet from the HTML5 boilerplate to prevent this error in the future.

Comment: @agconti - I was momentarily excited about this, but alas, I believe this process only suppressed the invalid character message but still produced this: http://screencast.com/t/dIbxFvzOZDp

Comment: @RudyHinojosa all that snippet does it that it checks if you script loaded successfully from a CDN an then if not, loads it from your server

Comment: @agconti Thank you good people.  I think this is going to ultimately be an issue with the script.  The line itself that inits the script for platform.min.js instantly fails.  No matter where I call it from.  I don't know if Visual Studio 2013 is having some type of internal conflict with the call to this script, or if this problem is global.  If I find an answer, I will be sure to update everyone. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: @agconti Problem solved! Going on agconti's hunch, I downloaded the platform.min.js to my own local script.  I referenced the file within from my Scripts directory and everything started working.

Comment: @RudyHinojosa updated with an answer for future people reading this thread. Please update it as you need.

Comment: @RudyHinojosa Hi, I'm from GoInstant and I'm looking for information as to why the CDN is/was failing.  It looks like maybe the script is getting truncated.  Do you have any details (besides the screenshot) from visual studio about how it failed to download completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the CDN is not serving your script correctly.

Use this [trick](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html#L24-L25) from the HTML5 Boilerplate to create a fall back to a local copy for when this happens:

```
<script src="https://cdn.goinstant.net/v1/platform.min.js"></script>
<script>window.goinstant || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/platform.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking into why the GoInstant CDN is failing, but I thought I'd suggest another way to fix it in the interim.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx details another way to do this auto-magically in ASP.net.  Scroll down to where you see "Fire up Visual Studio 2012 and make a new ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms application" and there's a quite long explanation of how to do it. Ultimately, this outputs a script-src-with-fallback set of tags similar to the one in @agconti's answer.